Question relating to uniform magnetic fields

My method for solving this problem is:

Use Faraday's Second Law of Electromagnetic Induction to find the induced emf: E = -dΦ/dt where Φ = BA. Since the area of the loop depends on the length of the bar as well as the displacement s from the top, the area A can be given by A = Ls. Since the bar will move downwards at a constant velocity v, the area A will increase over time: dA/dt = Lv. Now I substitute the expression for Φ into E, and I will obtain E = -BdA/dt = -BLv.
I then find the current using Ohm's law: I = E/Rbar
To find the resistance, I use the formula Rbar = ρL/A, where ρ is the resistivity of the bar and A is the cross-sectional area of the bar. But both are unknown.

Is it possible to find the numerical values of I and Rbar, as the question implies? Did I use the wrong formula somewhere, or skip over a few steps?
